# mlPushMenu Cannot read property 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have been trying to set up a mobile menu in WordPress using http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu. I have set up a custom walker for WP that is outputting the correct classes and structure however on the page load I continue to get

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null line 114
```

in the footer of the page I am calling

```
new mlPushMenu( document.getElementById( 'mp-menu' ), document.getElementById( 'trigger' ), {
            type : 'cover'
        } );
```

in the file mlpushmenu.js line 114 is

```
// open (or close) the menu
        this.trigger.addEventListener( this.eventtype, function( ev ) {
```

the file is located at - http://dev.qdconstruction.com/wp-content/themes/q-and-d/js/mlpushmenu.js?ver=20140206

I feel as though I have everything needed to have the menu work correctly however the JS error seems to be the reason why my menu with the cover effect is not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I see the error of my ways

```
<a data-rel="mobile-menu" href="#" id="trigger" class="menu-trigger">menu</a>
```

I needed ID = trigger set.